# Parse JSON Object to Array using JQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

**RESULT FROM WEB API**
    After calling the Web API, I am able to get the following JSON Format (result from Telerik Fiddler).

```
[
   {
      "modelEmployeeID": 1,
      "modelFirstName": "Mike",
      "modelLastName": "Tai",
      "modelBirthDate": "1900-01-01T00:00:00",
      "modelPosition": "IT Exec",
      "modelHireDate": "2017-01-01T00:00:00",
      "modelStateID": 1
   },
   {
      "modelEmployeeID": 2,
      "modelFirstName": "Sue",
      "modelLastName": "Yoong",
      "modelBirthDate": "1990-07-16T00:00:00",
      "modelPosition": "IT Manager",
      "modelHireDate": "2017-02-28T00:00:00",
      "modelStateID": 2
   }
]
```

**JQUERY**

```
**And I am calling the API using JQuery with the following method:**

var dbImpl = {
    load: function (loadOptions) {
       return $.getJSON('http://localhost:777/employee/testjson');
    },
};
```

**EXPECTED RESULT**
    I want the result having multiple object array: (I want the result labelled "1", currently the result is labelled "2")

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why you would expect `dbImpl` to look like `stateTest` when you explicitly define it as an object containing a function (`load`)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you expect `$.getJSON()` to return the JSON synchronously. It doesn't work like that, it's asynchronous (it just [uses Ajax internally](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)). I'm definitely not sure I know what you actually want, but surely you'd just do this?

```js
var dbImpl;
$.getJSON('http://localhost:777/employee/testjson', function(result) {
    dbImpl = result;
});
```

All that does is use `getJSON` to retrieve the JSON then assigns it to `dbImpl` in the success function. Assuming the data is the same as what you show in your question, `dbImpl` will then look like `statestest` does in the #1 screenshot in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method **:**

```
var statestest = jsonObj.map(item => [item]);
```

**Working Demo**

```js
var jsonObj = [
   {
      "modelEmployeeID": 1,
      "modelFirstName": "Mike",
      "modelLastName": "Tai",
      "modelBirthDate": "1900-01-01T00:00:00",
      "modelPosition": "IT Exec",
      "modelHireDate": "2017-01-01T00:00:00",
      "modelStateID": 1
   },
   {
      "modelEmployeeID": 2,
      "modelFirstName": "Sue",
      "modelLastName": "Yoong",
      "modelBirthDate": "1990-07-16T00:00:00",
      "modelPosition": "IT Manager",
      "modelHireDate": "2017-02-28T00:00:00",
      "modelStateID": 2
   }
];

var statestest = jsonObj.map(item => [item]);

console.log("statestest", statestest);
```